# Transforming from WGS84 UTM30N to British National Grid (BNG)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system, united-kingdom

I am using ArcGIS 10 and trying to work in British National Grid.

My shapefile is in WGS84 UTM30N.

I passed the shapefile across to a colleague and we both transformed into BNG.

When we compared the data there was a significant difference in our results.

I have since cross-checked with QGIS, Global mapper and a website or two and got a whole range of results but in general the most common is the result my colleague got.

1. What have I done wrong?
2. Why is there such a variation (~150m) in values? (1 or 2m error is
   probably ok for what I am looking at.)
3. Which value is "right"?

Comment: British National Grid which one did you pick? - the 'OSGB_1936_to_WGS_1984_Petroleum' is the most accurate for WGS84 re-projection http://geoxchange.esriuk.com/journal/tag/projections

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you and your colleague have chosen different datum transformations when converting from UTM to BNG.

This results in a datum shift (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid#Datum_shift_between_OSGB_36_and_WGS_84 ) - 150m would be expected.

I'm not sure of the best way to determine which shapefile is now "right" - I suspect that they are both still *right*, but *different*.